# The ONLY clause and inheriting from modules in a cascade

Tags: inheritance, module, fortran, fortran90

I have defined three types in three different modules (in three different files) using the following hierarchy:

```
MODULE module1 (low_level)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    TYPE type1
        real(kind=kind(0.d0)) :: var1
    END TYPE type1
    ... more declarations ...
END MODULE module1

MODULE module2 (medium_level)
    USE module1, only : type1
    IMPLICIT NONE
    TYPE type2
        type(type1) :: var2
    END TYPE type2
    ... more declarations ...
END MODULE module2

MODULE module3 (high_level)
    USE module2, only : type2
    IMPLICIT NONE
    TYPE type3
        type(type2) :: var3
    END TYPE type3
    ... more declarations ...
END MODULE module3
```

Now I have another module in which a module procedure is defined :

```
MODULE module4
    IMPLICIT NONE
    CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE sub1(var4)
        USE module3, only : type3
        IMPLICIT NONE
        type(type3), intent(inout) :: var4
        type(type1) :: var5
        ... using var5 ...
    END SUBROUTINE sub1
END MODULE module4
```

The compiler complains when compiling `module4` in the subroutine `sub1` :

```
Error: Derived type 'type1' at (1) is being used before it is defined
```

Adding a `USE module1, only : type1` in the subroutine solves the problem.

However, given that the subroutine `sub1` uses `module3` which uses `module2` which uses `module1`, I don't understand why I need to tell the compiler to "re-declare" `type1` which is already declared in `module1` and used by `module3` through `module2` by `USE` statements, the concept of inheritance should apply here. I don't see the advantage of using modules calling other modules if you have to write every module dependencies...

I surely may have misunderstood something, any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand the `only` clause on the `use` statements?  That (on a quick look) seems to be the answer to me, but if there's a more fundamental mis-understanding it would be better to approach that.

Comment: I admit the `only` clause is not necessary here since I have just declared one type in each module but it is just the beginning of my modules (which are much larger with much more declarations)

Comment: Well if you have `USE module2, only : type2` you cannot access `type1` from it, when you import only `type2`, can you? It seems you wanted `USE module2, only : type1, type2`.

Comment: You are both absolutely right. I misunderstood the `only`clause, the right way is the one suggested by @Vladimir. Thank you for your fast answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do

```
module module2
  USE module1, only : type1

module module3
  USE module2, only : type2
```

you cannot access `type1` in `module3`, because you import only `type2`.

It seems you wanted

```
module module3
  USE module2, only : type1, type2
```